# 3d Line graph in Java

Tags: java, 3d, charts

Is there any good open source library in Java which can be used to draw 3D dynamic charts, like JFreeChart does it for 2D?

Answer (score 1):

If you're up to coding to a more fundamental api (ie you have to draw your own lines to represent the chart values), two choices are:
    1. java3d.dev.java.net/
       (A display list abstraction) 
    2. kenai.com/projects/jogl/pages/Home
       (A Java wrapper to OpenGL)

Answer (score 0):

Can you define your use case, since JFreeChart can draw at least 3D line, bar and pie charts?

Comment: Actually I want to plot a dynamic graph which takes values of (x,y,z). Now I want to draw a 3D chart , i.e. showing all three axis x,y,z. Is it possible in JFreeChart. If yes then how? Also I am having a litte trouble with JFreechart as my update frequency is quite high, 10 fps. Due to this my system is utilizing 100% CPU usage. But I was thinking to solve this matter somehow. Wht I currently need is a 3D chart

Comment: JFreeChart can only draw 2D chart with a three-dimensional look, not real 3D chart as you want. I only know (but never used) http://sourceforge.net/projects/jplot3d/ for such cases, but unfortunately that's not really a chart library.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try http://www.jzy3d.org, which will really help you to do what you want.
Regards,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [Surface Plotter](http://code.google.com/p/surfaceplotter/). There is an online demo, it's LGPL, 100% pure java, and design for reuse.